# Drupal 7 profile2 pages not display profile

Tags: users

this is my problem:

I am using Profile2 Pages Module on Drupal 7.17, it's a test 
application with a fresh installation and only the listed modules installed.

Using the default Profile2 profile that come with the module ( its name is Main Profile ),
When i remove permission to the Authenticated user to edit his Profile2 Main Profile: own profile the user 
lose access to his own -profile2 page Main profile- , both the menu link and the permission to access the node get lost

this does NOT happen when the -profile2 Main profile- is displayed together with the user My account page

( you can achieve this by unchecking the "Provide a separate page for editing profiles." chkbox in Home » administration » structure » Profile types )

All dependencies are respected ( entity API >> profile2 >> profile2 pages )

i even tried by checking the chkbox in USER >> View user profiles   for the Authenticated user in Home » Administration » People  but no changes at all

Any advices is welcome, thanks.